# Partially filled circles in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am currently trying to plot a partially filled circle in the matplotlib scatter plot.
The [marker fill styles](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#marker-fill-styles) on the official documentation offers only half-filled or empty circles.
What I want is something similar to the following image:
[image]

Here I want to be able to control that, e.g., only the section 2-6 show up in a specific marker, while other markers show different ranges.

Does matplotlib support something like this? I understand that I probably need to partition the circle into 12 sections and assign them a specific color, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code you need for one marker, then just iterate over x0, y0 and use white as color for the wished "vanishing" segments.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, aspect='equal')

x0 = 0.2
y0 = 0.7
rho_marker = 0.05
n_marker = 14
theta = np.zeros((12, n_marker))

for j in range(12):
    theta[j, :] = np.linspace(float(j)/6.*np.pi, float(j+1)/6.*np.pi, n_marker)
    x = x0 + np.append(0, rho_marker*np.cos(theta[j]))
    y = y0 + np.append(0, rho_marker*np.sin(theta[j]))
    ax.fill(x, y)
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Here the resulting plot:
[image]